# passing objects from one activity to another one

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application in Android Studio and I know how to pass objects with an Intent but I wanna know if I can pass an object from one activity to another using getters and setters too and if it is possible how?

Comment: Intents are the primary mode of communication between activities in android. If you need to send your custom objects, you would need to make them implement `Serializable`. You can't have getters and setters "BETWEEN" activities. Activities represent individual screens. So it doesn't make sense to have it either.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a base type of object as:

Activity 1?

> Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
>
> intent.putExtra("data", somedata);
>
> startActivity(intent );

And at the Activity 2:

> Intent intent = getIntent();
>
> String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");

If you wanna pass one object, this one should implements Serializable.

To pass:

> intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);

To retrieve object in second Activity

> getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");

Comment: If you approve my answer I'll be glad to help too .   xD

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should use Intent to pass your objects using Serializable or Parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look on this code, you need to use like this:

```
public class Student implements Serializable
{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int rollno;
    String name;

    public int getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }
    public void setRollno(int rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Now To pass the object of Student class From Activity ‘A’ to activity ‘B’:

```
Student stud = new Student();
Intent aActivity = (A.this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("StudentObject", stud);
```

To retrieve object in second Activity i.e. in ‘B’ activity, write the below line:

```
Student studObject = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("StudentObject");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use getters and setters to pass an object to the NextActivity but this is possible if you intend to marshal the object and pass just the Components of the object one by one like String, int etc from the object to the NextActivity and this is not recommended except you want to get one or few components from the object.

The implications of breaking an object into pieces manually and putting each as an extra to intent is it consumes more resources and makes transition to the NextActivity slow. In order to avoid this kind of scenario, Android Parcelable and Java Serializable is introduced.

For information on Parcellable, visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable and on Serializable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html